# jQuery: Triggering a click event on a radio button on page load

Tags: jquery

I have 3 radio buttons which hide/show some div's.
The radio buttons are getting generated by a php script, I want jquery to check the first radio button (works already!) and then trigger the click function so it hides/shows the related stuff.

```
$("input:radio:first").attr("checked", true).trigger("click");
```

The .trigger("click"); actually does not work.

The click event of the radio buttons looks like this:

```
$("input[name='type']").on("click", function() { ... });
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Are you sure the input elements have the name of `type`? Is the event handler bound before you trigger the `click` event? p.s. you don't need `attr('checked', true)`, the radio will be checked by the `trigger('click')`: http://jsfiddle.net/pn6sp/

Comment: [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) example would be useful

Comment: The name is always type, checked that already. The trigger is under the .on("click")

Comment: Problem solved already! bArmageddon gave the solution.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Try doing it after DOM ready, like this:

```
$(function(){
  $("input:radio:first").click();
});
```

Maybe it hasn't finish loading. use `.click`.

Comment: I don't understand why it doesn't work if i put  "$("input:radio:first").click();"  in the $(document).ready(function() { ...}) instead it works if i put inside the $(document).ready(function() { ...})  in this way $(document).ready(function() { $(function(){ $("input:radio:first").click();}); }). Could you explain the reason? thank you