# Radio button trigger with Javascript

Tags: javascript, radio-button, dom-events

I have two radio buttons and I need first radio button to be check after window load with Javascript. By using its class automatically need to be triggered

Comment: And why not just add a `checked` attribute, you don't need javascript for this.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9922777/jquery-triggering-a-click-event-on-a-radio-button-on-page-load

Comment: Isn't the checked attribute what you are looking for? this will select the checked button by default. ```<input type="radio" name="defaultButton" value="" checked>```

Comment: @adeneo, he need to trigger event too, not only set checked

Comment: @ÁlvaroTouzón - that's not really clear from the question? But if so, that's trivial, just call the function, and he should still just set the attribute in the HTML

Comment: @adaneo, supose need trigger more relevant, but in practise you got reason

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the following way:

```js
function manageRadioButton() {
  var x = document.getElementsByClassName("radio");
  x[0].checked = true;
}
```

```html
<body onload="manageRadioButton()">
  <input type="radio" class="radio" name="gender" value="male"> Male<br>
  <input type="radio" class="radio" name="gender" value="female"> Female<br>
</body>
```

Answer (score 1):

Adding this JavaScript to the `body` of your page will trigger a self executing function when the page loads and will check the radio button. You can add the extra logic you mentioned into the function.

```
<input type="radio" name="radioButton" id="radioButton_1" value="">

<script>
    (function() {
        document.getElementById("radioButton_1").checked = true;
    })();
</script>
```